# Whats shoud be the regular expression for the following text

Tags: python, regex

```
<p class="body">
  Giving the meeting of NITI Aayog in New Delhi a miss, West Bengal Chief        Minister and Trinamool Congress chairperson Mamata Banerjee said in Bardhaman on Wednesday that the Centre should withdraw the land acquisition ordinance.
</p>
```

Just to get the content between `<p class="body">` and `</p>`

`re.search(">(.+?)<",text)` is returning None

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's not working? Also, please realized that regular expressions [are not the best tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for general HTML parsing...

Comment: I accidentally flagged this as spam. Without the code markup it looked like someone was trying to squeeze in a political statement. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: re.search("<p class="body"> (.+?) </p>",text)

Comment: I am not able to understand why is it returning Null value each and every time

Comment: I don't know python but is there a modifier so the `.` extends to new lines as well?

Comment: For what I know '.' will not represent new line

Comment: Maybe this would be useful, https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S

Comment: I also used re.search(">(.+?)<",str(each),re.M) but same result

Comment: also this: val =  re.search("""<p class="body">\n
   (.+?)\n
   </p>""",str(each),re.X)

Comment: Thanks guys : re.search(">(.+?)<",str(each),re.DOTALL) worked perfectly for me...

Answer (score 0):

The `.` by default doesn't include new lines so your current regex doesn't match.

> re.DOTALL
>   Make the '.' special character match any character at all, including a newline; **without this flag, '.' will match anything except a newline**.

This doc has a list of modifiers that can be used to alter how the regex functions https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S.

So the `.+?` only matches the following without the modifier:

```
<p class="body">
```

with the modifier you will get:

```
<p class="body">
  Giving the meeting of NITI Aayog in New Delhi a miss, West Bengal Chief        Minister and Trinamool Congress chairperson Mamata Banerjee said in Bardhaman on Wednesday that the Centre should withdraw the land acquisition ordinance.
</p>
```

You should consider using a parser for this though. This regex will fail with any additional elements in your search string, for example:

```
<p class="body">
  Giving the meeting of <em>ITI</em> Aayog in New Delhi a miss, West Bengal Chief        Minister and Trinamool Congress chairperson Mamata Banerjee said in Bardhaman on Wednesday that the Centre should withdraw the land acquisition ordinance.
</p>
```

You can see this in action [here](http://pythex.org/?regex=%3E(.%2B%3F)%3C&test_string=%3Cp%20class%3D%22body%22%3E%0A%20%20Giving%20the%20meeting%20of%20NITI%20Aayog%20in%20New%20Delhi%20a%20miss%2C%20West%20Bengal%20Chief%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Minister%20and%20Trinamool%20Congress%20chairperson%20Mamata%20Banerjee%20said%20in%20Bardhaman%20on%20Wednesday%20that%20the%20Centre%20should%20withdraw%20the%20land%20acquisition%20ordinance.%0A%3C%2Fp%3E&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0).